# How to define a variable in an element multiple actions

Tags: jquery, variables

I want to assign a variable for a global context in element multiple actions

Is there a way to assign correctly `$fieldContainer` once and simply use it in the multi actions for the element `".field-input"` ?

Thanks by advance ;)

Regards

```
$('.field-input')
    .focus(function () {
        $fieldContainer = $(this).parent().parent();
        _hasError = false;
        $fieldContainer.addClass('is-focused has-label');
    })
    .blur(function () {
        $fieldContainer = $(this).parent().parent();
        $fieldContainer.removeClass('is-focused');
        if ($(this).val() == '') $fieldContainer.removeClass('has-label');
    })
    .each(function () {
        $fieldContainer = $(this).parent().parent();
        if ($(this).val() != '') $fieldContainer.addClass('has-label');
    })
```

Comment: I don't think so.  You could write a function that determines the parent's parent by passing it $(this), but I don't think combining the selectors gains you anything.

Comment: Right that's what is thought too but not really sure.
Thanks for your answer